# How to integrate Admob with xib instead of storyboard?

Tags: ios, admob

The official quick start guide from Admob is using storyboard. My question is how to do it for xib?

Comment: Whether you're implementing AdMob on a storyboard or an xib is irrelevant. Are you implementing banner ads or interstitial ads? What have you tried so far? Swift or Objective C? Have you tried searching for similar questions?

Comment: I'm implementing banner ads. I've followed all the steps in Admob iOS quick guide except the storyboard part: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Comment: I'm new in iOS development. I'm developing app using Objective C. There is a similar unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225626/google-admob-not-working-with-xib-files-why